# Google Maps API cannot process one specific address

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We have a working Google Maps API (V2) module working correctly on our custom made CMS.

I cannot figure out why but this code seems to be having troubles processing one specific Address. What's weird is that the address can be found normally on Google Maps.

Here are two examples, one address that works perfectly and the address that Google Maps API cannot find :

**Working Address** : via Zups 2, 7013 Domat/Ems

```
<script> 
initialize( "googlemap-viazups17013domat/ems", "via Zups 2 7013 Domat/Ems" )Marly" ) 
</script>
```

[working HTML output (cleaned up)](http://pastebin.com/X1V6hPqz)

**Unworking Address** : via Zups 1, 7013 Domat/Ems

```
<script>
initialize( "googlemap-viazups17013domat/ems", "via Zups 1 7013 Domat/Ems" )
</script>
```

[non Working HTML output (cleaned up)](http://pastebin.com/wuv7sDgf)

Also note that if I change the address to display Number 2 of the same street it works! But Number 1 never works.

––––

Edit :

Here is the initialize function :

```
function initialize( div, address ) {
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 15,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      scrollwheel:false
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById( div ), myOptions);
    //map.disableDragging()
    if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                         map: map, 
                         position: results[0].geometry.location
                          });
            } else {
                 alert("Impossible de localiser " + address);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Google Maps API v2 no longer works, and your request is really being processed through API v3.  See https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/v2tov3

Comment: ... although looking at your code in http://www.cd-auto.ch/data/standards/js/map.js it looks like you're using v3 not v2

Comment: Add your `initialize` function to your question please

Comment: It may be right. I can't tell for sure which version is actually used for now as there were some recent upgrades made by other developers. 

I just added the initialize function to the question.

Comment: You have a div with ID `googlemap-viazups17013domat/ems` which doesn't work, but another one with ID `googlemap-viazups27013domat/ems` which does work?  You might want to update your question with HTML that demonstrates both the working and non-working divs

Comment: Okay I updated with two links to see the HTML Output of both working and non working div IDs. My guess is that Google API can't resolve a conflict between a "place" (commerce) and an address (street and n°). Looks like a bug actually... if I pass GPS coordinates it works...

Comment: Your not working HTML has a div with ID `googlemap-viazups27013domat/ems` but your JS code refers to ID of `googlemap-viazups17013domat/ems`.  These IDs need to match.

Comment: Oups. Really sorry for the mistake. The links to the working and non working were mixed up. I updated the question so you have now the working address with via Zups 2 at the top (with the right HTML) and the non working address with via Zups 1 at the bottom. So the mistake is not were you suggested duncan. Sorry again.